# Pasting cells into Excel loses formatting.

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I borrowed [this script](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/amail4.htm) to copy ranges from Excel and paste them into a new Outlook draft.

While I'm proficient in Javascript, Apps Script and one or two other areas, I'm VERY new to VBA, so I've modified this to pretty much do what I want (Paste multiple ranges in one after the other), but for some reason, even though I'm using the following code snippet:

```
'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
rntest.Copy
Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
With TempWB.Sheets(1)
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
    .Cells(1).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    On Error Resume Next
    .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
    .DrawingObjects.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
End With
```

my conditional formatting disappears for some cells, and completely reverses for others (What would be green turns red, and cells with '0%' in them which should be one colour, end up being completely blank).

Specifically, I believe that the line '.Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False' is correct.

Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong? Again, just picking up VBA recently, so I assume my problem is very basic.

Comment: It sounds like the references in your conditional formatting formulas are off kilter. Are they set correctly in terms of absolute/relative. Are the pointing at the new workbook?

Comment: Ah, I see, because when pasting to the new workbook, the references for the formatting disappear. Testing, this does appear to be the problem (When pasting the conditional formatting to a new sheet, the same conditional formatting switch happens). Is there a way for me to use 'PasteSpecial' (Or another function) to paste just the current cell colour, and not the conditional  formatting? Or alternatively, to keep the formatting to refer to the original workbook? (If that makes sense).